# How do I get around asp.net automatically generating IDs when I'm using jquery that needs the IDs?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery's popular Validate plugin to validate all my fields. This works great when the input fields are not running at server and thus not renaming all the IDs and Names for the input.

I'm wondering if there is a different way to select the input in the jquery so I can still use the plugin. The jquery is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true,
            },
        }
    });
});
```

Currently, if I use an `<asp:TextBox.../>` the ID comes out to "ContentPlaceHolderBody_firstName" and the name comes out to "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$firstName".

I even tried replacing the name in the jquery to reflect both the ID and the name to no avail.

What is the best way around this? Can I add a class and select that way? And if so, what would the jquery selector look like?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to asp.net 4.0

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: This is the larger-term fix I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

You can write some inline server side code like:

```
$('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
            <%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>: {
                required: true,
            },
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ClientIDMode property to static

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The jquery selector for a class would be $(".classname)

Comment: $('.classname') - missing a quote

Answer (score 0):

in `.net 4.0` you can set set the `ClientIDMode="static"` and have predictable control ids

e.g.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

and in javascript side you can have the id of your choice

```
$("#Label1").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your asp control and then select on that class instead of the ID